# "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" not working on my device (HTC Wildfire) - how to debug?

Tags: android

I face really frustrating problem.

I created SMS receiver as most online and book's tutorials say.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application android:name="roboguice.application.RoboApplication"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:debuggable="true" >    

    <!-- ... other stuffs here ... -->

    <receiver android:name=".receivers.SmsReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

SmsReceiver.java:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "SmsReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SMS received!");
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS received.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**While it works correctly on Emulator (Android 2.2) it doesn't work on my HTC Wildfire** (Android 2.2.1, not rooted).

The main problem is that I'm new into Android deveopment and I have completely no idea how to debug it.

Can I find out something usefull with LogCat logs sendt from my HTC device while it receives SMS message? Why is my device different!?

Comment: The SMS broadcast is ordered, so step 1 is to yank up your receivers priority something fierce. You do this by setting the android:priority attribute on your intent-filter to a recklessly high value and testing again. Try something like 2147483647.

Comment: It doesn't change anything :(. No log in LogCat, no Toast shown, just nothing on device (on Emulator it works as expected). I'm wondering why I get such log in LogCat when phone receives sms message: "11-06 23:43:20.540: DEBUG/SMSDispatcher(171): dispatchWapPushToCIQ  >>>". Could that be the reason or any trace?

Comment: Hm, try downloading an existing SMS-filter (from Market) or something similar to your Wildfire and test that first - it could be something wonky in the HTC phone (has happened before..)

Comment: Thanks :), that was good trace. I've find out that "GO SMS Pro" application was blocking this Intent for my app (more details in my solution-answer to this topic).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Reason & Solution**:

I've fix that. "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" was not working because I had "GO SMS Pro" application installed on my device and there was "Disable other message notification" option checked (*"Disable other SMS related apps' notification in notification bar, avoid duplicate notifications."*). Unchecking it fixed my problem.

How to make sure that my broadcast receiver will receive this intent even if some other app blocks it? Due to "android:priority" ([Intercept SMS messages in Android and prevent them appearing in Messaging App](http://www.it-hall.com/1871/intercept-sms-messages-in-android-and-prevent-them-appearing-in-messaging-app/)) how can I know what "priority" is set for "GO SMS Pro" app?

Comment: thx, this works, in the "advance settings" -> "Other Settings" -> (Uncheck) "Disable other message notification".

Answer (score 10):

For your *Reason & Solution*:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
    System.out.println("Receiver name:" + info.activityInfo.name + "; priority=" + info.priority);
}
```

And just look through your output for the GO SMS Pro crap. It's probably ridiculously high.

Comment: Thanks a milion :)! Now I see that guys from "GO SMS Pro" made two receivers with priority equal to max integer value (2147483647). Their app is probably calling abortBroadcast() on SMS_RECEIVED. So is there any way I can fight with their app? Documentation says nothing about what happens when priorities are equal, but as I find out "Go SMS Pro" app is called first, consumes my SMS_RECEIVED intent and my app isn't called as a result :(.

Comment: It's "installed first wins" if I remember correctly. Best bet is to warn the customer that GO SMS Pro is a known problem (dialog, notification or what have you).

Comment: Thanks again. Probably best solution would be some extension of what you wrote: to use code above and check if there are any other receivers registered for SMS_RECEIVED intent with max priority. Then to warn user that listed apps could cause a problem.

Comment: Just a small suggestion: you would better use `Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` constant

Answer (score 2):

GO SMS PRO has priority is 2^31-1 = 2147483647. So your app can not receiver any message because GO SMS service aborted other broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this code is right. You might not be seeing the `Toast` message, But the logs would have come. Check the Logcat and you should see the log you have put.

You should be using `Notifications` inside `BroadcastReceivers` and not `Toast`s.