# Android Broadcast receiver not receving income SMS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have written a SMS receiver for catching income SMS , everything looks fine but it doesn't 
works and no SMS income received by the receiver . this is the codes and manifest content.
As I remember I had same app has written in `android 2.3` working fine but this code is running in `android 4.x` which is not functioning properly. what is the problem ? Is it depends on security issues of `android 4.x` ?

**Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name="SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

---

**Java Code:**

```
 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Logger.i("INCOMMING SMS...");
    if (action == SMS_RECEIVED) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
            if (messages.length > -1) {
                String sendr = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                Logger.i(sendr);
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030777/android-provider-telephony-sms-received-not-working-on-my-device-htc-wildfire

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319987/sms-received-not-working-on-ice-cream-sandwich

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I've fixed it by adding two more actions to the manifest registered receiver so it will look like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        <action android:name="com.your.package.android.action.broadcast"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

also add permission :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

And for comparsion of Strings do not use equals operator, but equals method instead.(Note. equalsIgnoreCase() should be better for you.)

so it will be like:

```
if(SMS_RECEIVED.equalsIgnoreCase(action))
{
//continue
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and after much research on the net, I found the problem. Your application is not started and the Emulator Control doesn't send the option **--include-stopped-packages** as the adb command can do it. It is a feature introduced with Android 3.x.

So, your receiver never receives the broadcast because your application is not started.
To start it first, open a console from your system and type the following command:

```
*adb -e shell am broadcast -a android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED --include-stopped-packages*
```

Your BroadcastReceveiver receive an empty SMS.

After this command, your process is displayed in the Devices view, and you can send SMS from your emulator control.