# SMS Broadcast Receiver not called on Android 6

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am trying to capture the SMS received on the phone, but when the phone receives an SMS message the method 'onReceive' is not called. This is my code:

**I have the BroadcastReceiver is declared in the 'AndroidManifest.xml' inside the tag 'application':**

```
    <receiver android:name=".util.IncomingSmsReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**This is the IncomingSmsReceiver.java**

```
public class IncomingSmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive executed");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
           ...
        }
   }
}
```

I'm doing the tests on an emulator Google Nexus 5 with Android 6. When I send a sms (fake) in the emulator a notification appears as if it was received really well and I can use it in the default application that brings the emulator. In the logcat of Android Studio does not appear that you have run the method `onReceive`, or the code written inside.I've tried to change the priority, I've tried using `android:enabled="true"`, I've tried using `registerReceiver` and I have not gotten it to work. Does anyone know if I miss something?

Comment: Yes I have declared these permissions:
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />`

Comment: I have an activity that is executed by clicking on a button, and in it I try to use `registerReceiver`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a default messaging app with "Disable other apps" flag on?

Please see this:

["android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" not working on my device (HTC Wildfire) - how to debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030777/android-provider-telephony-sms-received-not-working-on-my-device-htc-wildfire/8036900#8036900)

Edit:

Since you are using Android 6, you should use the new permissions model. Check this out:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I have read that response, but it is not I think that is my case. I use a clean emulator, only have installed my application, everything else comes from the factory.

Comment: @AnderAcosta Edited my answer, please check again

Comment: Works! Thanks! I am going to edit the title of my question.

Comment: @AnderAcosta Glad to be of assistance! Since the problem seems to be solved, you might want to [mark one of the answers as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark (✓) icon next to the answer on the left. Doing so will mark the question as answered, and will also award both you and me a few reputation points.

Comment: Dude, you saved my life... I have Xiaomi Mi 5 device and just couldn't get my BroadcastReceiver to work when receiving SMS that I send from the same device. After reading your post, I went to my device's main messaging app settings and disabled "Mi Message" option. It turns out that it enables sending messages over Wi-Fi to other Mi devices, so when I sent messages to my self, they travelled over Wi-Fi, and I believe that's what caused my BroadcastReceiver not to work.